# Projection mean of data matrix with mean 0

Tags: linear-algebra

Given matrix $X$, where rows are data, and the matrix $X$ is mean-centered (mean of all rows is $0$), and projecting it on some eigenvector in PCA (or just on some eigenvector of $X^T*X$), how to prove that the projection mean is zero too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ have rows denoted $v_i$. Since $X$ is mean-centered, $\sum_j v_j = \vec{0}$. Now let $u\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ be a unit vector. Projecting the data $X$ onto $u$ (i.e. reducing dimensionality to 1D) gives the "new" data $w=Xu$.

But this projection is mean-centered too, because:
\begin{align}
\sum_i w_i = \sum_i v_i \cdot u = u\cdot\sum_i v_i = u\cdot\vec{0} = {0}
\end{align}

Hopefully that's what you were asking!

Comment: yep, this is exactly what I asked thx ^^ somehow didn't think that it does not matter which vector we project onto as long as it is unit-vector